# Issue in Downloading File In Dropbox Version 2 Php Api

Tags: php, dropbox-api

Hy Everyone,
I am using this code to download file from Dropbox Version 2 Php Api.But I don't get success yet in File downloading.Lets have a look on the script which i am using

```
function dbx_get_file($token, $in_filepath, $out_filepath)
{
$out_fp = fopen($out_filepath, 'w+');
if ($out_fp === FALSE)
    {
    echo "fopen error; can't open $out_filepath\n";
    return (NULL);
    }

$url = 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download';

$header_array = array(
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token,
    'Content-Type:',
    'Dropbox-API-Arg: {"path":"' . $in_filepath . '"}'
);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header_array);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $out_fp);

$metadata = null;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, function ($ch, $header) use (&$metadata)
    {
    $prefix = 'dropbox-api-result:';
    if (strtolower(substr($header, 0, strlen($prefix))) === $prefix)
        {
        $metadata = json_decode(substr($header, strlen($prefix)), true);
        }
    return strlen($header);
    }
);

$output = curl_exec($ch);

if ($output === FALSE)
    {
    echo "curl error: " . curl_error($ch);
    }

curl_close($ch);
fclose($out_fp);

return($metadata);
} // dbx_get_file()
```

Calling this Function Here.

```
dbx_get_file("<Access-token>", '/Screenshot_1.png', 'Screenshot_1.png');
```

I also replaced this "Access-token" with my Dropbox O-auth 2 Access Token.
Please suggest me the answer what i am doing wrong?Or is there any other way to download File from Dropbox using DropBox Version 2 PHP Api.
Thanks

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: Problem is that file is downloading but empty...

Comment: I don't see `fwrite`. Do you use it?

Comment: Thanks for the Reply @u_mulder .I am not using fwrite.Can you brief where should i use this..?

Comment: This line already should tell curl to write the data to the file: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $out_fp);`. This code is working for me. You should check if the remote file happens to actually be zero bytes, and that you have write access to the local file.

Comment: Hy @Greg Thanks for the Reply.Remote image is Fineand of 57Kb.File is created on my local server but it corrupted.What will be the reason?

Comment: Local file that is created on local server is 25Kb but orignal file is 57 Kb...SO file gets corrupt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done it using Requests Library https://github.com/rmccue/Requests/
Here is my Code

```
include('Requests-master/library/Requests.php');
Requests::register_autoloader();
$token="Your Access Token is here";
$response = 
Requests::post("https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download", array(
'Authorization' => "Bearer ".$token,
'Dropbox-Api-Arg' => json_encode(array('path' => '/Screenshot_1.png')),
));
$fileContent = $response->body;
/*Download the file using file_put_contents method*/
file_put_contents("Screenshot_1.png",$fileContent);
$metadata = json_decode($response->headers['Dropbox-Api-Result'], true);
echo "File " . $metadata["name"] . " has the rev " . $metadata["rev"] . ".\n";
```

File is downloading Successfully... :)